# .asp Not Recognized: 500 - Internal server error

Tags: html, css, asp-classic, ssi

I recently switched some pages (all of poetry-lyrics and writings) from .html to .asp. I needed to add a footer and header include. So I have changed the file type, and added the new .txt includes for all the pages. Now When i click them they all say 500 - Internal server error.

Live Example:
http://www.jasontanzer.com/poetry-lyrics.asp
(click any link)

What does this mean? As far as I see, they should be working fine. Anyone see anything wrong here? Thanks Very Much.

James

Comment: Without seeing how you have added the includes and what they contain, it is very difficult to answer the question. It can be any of thousands of reasons.

Comment: What @Oded says. Also, there will be a log file somewhere, telling you what exactly goes wrong where

Comment: How is this PHP related?

Comment: OK, what can I deliver which would make this diagnosis easier for all the smarty pants hot shots out there? (View Source Wont Cut it I Take It?)

Answer (score 0):

@KemoSabe: Your includes should look like this within `yourfile.asp`:

```
<!-- #include file="header.txt" -->
Your content
<!-- #include file="footer.txt" -->
```

Since your site is hosted on IIS7, I suggest you have a look at this site as well for other common issues: http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2007/05/21/tips-for-classic-asp-developers-on-iis7.aspx